# How to resolve libosxfuse versions dependencies

Tags: macos, ntfs, osx-el-capitan, ntfs-3g

I'm trying to mount a NTFS volume for read-write following [this](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-write-to-ntfs-external-disk-drives-from-os-x-10-11-el-capitan/) explanation.

But when I attach the voluem, I get this error in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/ntfs-3g_2015-12-30-131038-1_morgan.crash`

```
Process:               ntfs-3g [2864]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/ntfs-3g/2015.3.14/bin/ntfs-3g
Identifier:            ntfs-3g
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)

OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.2 (15C50)

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/ntfs-3g/bin/ntfs-3g
  Reason: Incompatible library version: ntfs-3g requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libosxfuse.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0

Binary Images:
    0x7fff69d95000 -     0x7fff69dcbfa7  dyld (360.18) <1A7F8274-FC32-3B86-9979-66B8F2B7B5E2> /usr/lib/dyld
```

I installed OSXFUSE with MacFUSE compatibility but same error.

Answer (score 4):

Got the same issue. Resolved as: "You need to install osxfuse version 3.0.3 or later."
Check here: https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/releases